# Reshape np.array to prevent error: skearn GPR XA and XB must have the same number of columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I want to use the Gaussian process regressor from scikit-learn. My data used for prediction and function, which performs gpr, looks like as follows:

training data:

```
X[[ 43.3301   -196.211    1157.89        2.71431  -191.664    1159.45
-28.9847   -191.544    1158.88        5.99311  -218.226    1229.12
 38.9442   -214.853    1256.5 ]
[ 43.3212   -196.12     1157.79        2.7885   -191.587    1159.45
-29.0067   -191.53     1158.88        5.94141  -218.028    1229.11
 38.8952   -214.711    1256.48]...] <class 'numpy.ndarray'> (14, 15)
```

target data:

```
y[[ 9.14779  -186.67     1294.53]
 [ 9.12453  -186.559    1294.33 ]
 [ 8.50554  -186.254    1293.22]...] <class 'numpy.ndarray'> (14, 3)
```

and test data

```
x[[ -90.23126221 -245.3088  675.835]
 [ -63.30067444 -256.1264  752.844]
 [ -28.84734154 -236.4492  642.7713]...] <class 'numpy.ndarray'> (14, 3)


def doGPR(self, inputData, targetData, testData):

    kernel = ConstantKernel(1.0, (1e-3,1e3)) * RBF(10.0, (1e-2,1e2)) + WhiteKernel(0.1, (1e-10, 0.5))
    gpr = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel= kernel, n_restarts_optimizer= 0, normalize_y= True)  
    gpr.fit(X, y)
    predictedData, sigma = gpr.predict(x, return_std=True)
```

In the prediction phase, I get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sklearn/gaussian_process/gpr.py", line 315, in predict
K_trans = self.kernel_(X, self.X_train_)
File "sklearn/gaussian_process/kernels.py", line 683, in __call__
return self.k1(X, Y) + self.k2(X, Y)
File "sklearn/gaussian_process/kernels.py", line 758, in __call__
return self.k1(X, Y) * self.k2(X, Y)
File "sklearn/gaussian_process/kernels.py", line 1215, in __call__
metric='sqeuclidean')
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/spatial/distance.py", line 2031, in cdist raise ValueError('XA and XB must have the same number of columns '
ValueError: XA and XB must have the same number of columns (i.e. feature dimension.)
```

Does it mean that I should also bring my training data to shape (x, 3)? How can I do that with this nested array?

Thank you!

Comment: Why does your `X` training data have 15 columns and test data have 3 columns?

Comment: Yes, this doesn't seem consistent.

Comment: Actually the columns of `X` can be more or less than `15`, because it changes dynamically. I don't get the problem

Comment: @mystic.06 that is the problem.  If you train your algorithm to predict `y` from `x1` and `x2`, then the algorithm will only handle inputs containing BOTH `x1` and `x2`.  If you don't know `x2` for an input, one possibility may be to impute it with the mean of the training `x2` values, but how well that will work, I know not.

Comment: Your training `X` is of the format `.shape = n_datapoints by n_features`.  If you're not sure which features are which in your test data vs your train data, then you're gonna have a bad time.

Comment: @Scott my problem is not about knowing the fitness of train and test data but shapes of both. and how to bring the `X (14, 15)` to `X (?, 3)`

Comment: So I reshaped the X with X= X.reshape(5,14, 3)) Now every data contains 3 columns as features (Shape of X= (5,14,3), y=(14,3) and x= (14,3)). With `gpr.fit(X[0], y)` I can predict

Comment: You can reshape it to have 3 columns with, for example, `.reshape(-1,3)`.  You could also take, say, the last 3 columns as `X[:,-4:]`.  I'm almost certain neither of those will be useful, since the *meaning* of the columns in the train data will be different than in the test data.  What you want is to identify the 3 columns  in the training data that you actually need.